# Fetching Updated Data using getServerSideProps in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

So, I have a public page which I am pre-rendering using getServerSideProps in Nextjs. Now, once I make updates to the data in the page, the new updates do not show until I re-build. Please how do I handle this?

As an example, let's say I have a blog post page: "https://example.com/blog/what-is-stackoverflow". In this page I am fetching some pictures by making an api call to a database. I have now updated the number of pictures through another api from let's say 2 to 3.
On visiting that particular blog page again, I am only seeing 2 pictures instead of 3 from the most recent update. But if I rebuild my next-js website, I now get to see the 3 pictures.

Here is a copy of the code:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { data: professionalData } = await client.query({
    query: GET_PROFESSIONAL,
    variables: {
      uuid: params.uuid,
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      data: professionalData.user,
    },
  };
};
```

Thank you as I await a response

Comment: Are you experiencing this in development and production mode? Could you show us the code related to the page? `getServerSideProps` gets called on each page request. Unless you're caching the page (or the API data) somehow, making a new page request should trigger new API requests and fetch the most recent data.

Comment: Many thanks @juliomalves It seems only to happen in production environment. While running it locally (development mode) returns the updated data which is what I expect in the production environment.

**Here is a copy of the code:**

`export const getServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { data: professionalData } = await client.query({
    query: GET_PROFESSIONAL,
    variables: {
      uuid: params.uuid,
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      data: professionalData.user,
    },
  };
};`

Comment: Where are you hosting your app in production? Do you see any `Cache-Control` header on the page response that would suggested it is being cached?

Comment: Yeah, I have checked the cache-control and nothing seems to indicate the data is being cached. Here is the cache policy of the **response headers**:
`cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate`

That of the **request-headers**:
`cache-control: no-cache`